# How to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded to slack via python slackclient?

Tags: python, slack-api

I am trying to use the api call `users.profile.get` to find a users profile picture. The problem is that the request requires not JSON, but URL encoded queries (I think?). I have the user id already, but I need to know how to send it to slack correctly, preferably with the `api_call` method.How would I go along doing this?

Here is the documention: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.get

```py
for users in collection.find():
                start_date, end_date = users['start_date'], users['end_date']

                user_data = client.api_call('users.profile.get',
                                            """What would I do here?""")
                user_images[users['user_id']] = user_data['image_72']
                block.section(
                    text=
                    f'from *{date_to_words(start_date[0], start_date[1], start_date[2])}* to *{date_to_words(end_date[0], end_date[1], end_date[2])}*'
                )
                block.context(data=((
                    'img', user_images[users['user_id']],
                    '_error displaying image_'
                ), ('text',
                    f'<!{users["user_id"]}>. _Contact them if you have any concerns_'
                    )))
```

Comment: would you be ok with a solution using the current version of the slackclient or do you need the old one for Python 2?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I am using slackclient 2.0, so yes, that would be okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameters of the API as names arguments in your function call.

For users.get.profile you want to provide the user ID, e.g. "U1245678".

Then your call would look like this (with slackclient v1):

```
response = sc.api_call(
  "users.profile.get",  
  user="U12345678"
)
assert response["ok"]
user_data = response["profile"]
```

Or like this with slackclient v2:

```
response = sc.users_profile_get(user="U12345678")
assert response["ok"]
user_data = response["profile"]
```

To answer your question: You do not have to worry about how the API is called, since that is handled by library. But technically most of Slack's API endpoints accepts parameters both as URL endocded form and JSON.

Comment: When I run the script, I receive the error `slack.errors.BotUserAccessError: The method 'users_profile_get' cannot be called with a Bot Token.` Do I need to have more OAuth permissions?

Comment: No. This method can not be called with a bot token. You need to use the user token aka or "OAuth Access Token" instead.